# Portable 4k monitor with high refresh rate

Tags: monitors, portable, 4k

I am looking for a portable monitor with a refresh rate higher than 60 Hz and a resolution of 3840 by 2160. It is easy enough to find each of these features individually, but I have not been able to find them in a single device. A size around 17-18 inches would be ideal,  but 15 or 16 would also be fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any portable monitor that uses USB-C will not be capable of 4K over 60hz. All of the possible display signals USB-C can support max out at around the bandwidth required for 3840x2160@60hz. You will have to find a "portable" display that has a full HDMI 2.1+ or DP 1.4+ port. As well as a GPU that can support those signals too.

Comment: @Romen - Of course. Do you know of such a display?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you knew about that limitation. "Portable" generally implies USB-C for displays these days because it's an ideal all-in-one connector. There are some older portable displays that use a separate power supply & HDMI but because they're older they're not HDMI 2.1, or even 4K. I don't know of any new portable displays that don't use USB-C or Thunderbolt (same DP mode limitations). Let alone one that is above 60hz!

Comment: To add to @Romen 's suggestions. Very few 4K monitors I've seen even go over 60 Hz, and need a decent graphics card even to support that rate. Any 4K portable monitor is likely to have very low battery life due to the power drain. I don't think they really exist on the consumer market due to pricing, battery.